# The uninstall.dat file cannot be found in postgreSQL

Tags: python, database, postgresql, uninstallation

I want to uninstall PostgreSQL and reinstall it again. I found out that the application was not properly installed.

I have tried all the steps to uninstall it but it still results in the same outcome.

After I click "uninstall", I get this message:

> "The uninstall.dat file cannot be found and is required to uninstall the application, aborting".

There is an uninstall.dat file in PostgreSQL. I've tried changing it in Notepad and Editpad but still get the "cannot be found" message. And I've tried many times without success.

Please is there any solution to this issue?

Comment: I am having the same problem with the BigSQL installer on windows. This just annoys that these idiots have come up with an installer that is plain broken

Answer (score 1):

I used trial version of the professional edition of revo uninstaller https://www.revouninstaller.com

Managed to remove all the junk left by the Postgresql installer

Comment: Thanks for the resource.